# Can I create a unique constraint on Loopback4's hasManyThrough (M:M) table

Tags: node.js, orm, many-to-many, loopback4

## Preamble

I'm somewhat new to Loopback 4, and I have successfully created 2 working CRUD controllers, repositories, models, etc. I have **Users** and **Organizations**, and I am have successfully created a M:M relation between **Users** and **Organizations** using the [relation generator](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Relation-generator.html). So, I can create a user, create an organization, and separately I can link them together in a many-to-many table called "membership". All of this follows (as far as I know) loopback best practices per their [docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/HasManyThrough-relation.html).

## Question:

***How do I make sure that each record in the membership table is unique?***

[here's an example of my table with duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AySRD.png)

For example, User #1, Jeff, joins Organization #1, Amazon. Some erroneous code then attempts to add Jeff to Amazon a 2nd time, I want this to fail.

I was thinking I could simply check the database if the record exists, but it seems cleaner to add this constraint to the model, so that any attempted insert would fail if duplicate. I have dug around in the docs and haven't found anything.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In database design, a unique constraint would be enforced by a compound/composite key on the junction table. This would enforce a unique pair of `orgId` and `userId`.

Hence, the junction table should have only 2 columns:

- orgId
- userId

To create a composite key in LoopBack 4, update the through model as follows:

```js
// Some parts were omitted for bevity

@model()
export class OrgUser extends Entity {
  @property({id: 1})
  orgId: number;
  
  @property({id: 2})
  userId: number;

  constructor(data?: Partial<OrgUser>) {
    super(data);
  }
}
```